# How do I reference a dynamic variable inside angular expression braces?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've looked high and low for an answer to this, but nothing that directly addresses this. The issue is this -- I have a function that gets a list of calendars from an endpoint. I have another function that counts the number of events for each calendar. I have it creating a dynamic variable every time it's called in the ng-repeat list, attaching the calendar ID to the word "count" as the variable name.

```
function getEventsCount(calendarId) {
  if(calendarId !== '') {
    calendarService.getCalendarEvents(calendarId, fromDate, toDate).then(function (result) {
      if(isSuccessResponse(result)) {
        $scope['count' + calendarId] = result.events.length;
      } else {
        $scope.errorMessage = errorText + result.errorMessage;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

In the HTML I want to display the numerical count of events for each calendar, but since we're iterating through an ng-repeat list which will return any given number of calendar IDs, I don't know what the variable name for count will be, so I need angular to somehow parse the variable name inside of those braces for the value.

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item" data-ng-repeat="calendar in calendarList.calendars" data-ng-init="getEventsCount(calendar.id)">
    <a roll="button" class="btn-link" data-ng-click="showCalendar(calendar.id, calendar.summary)">{{calendar.summary}} ({{count + calendar.id}})</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Forgive me if the question is muddy, I'll be happy to clarify if needed.

Comment: Why can't you assign the `count` property to your `calender` object and just use that instead of some complex scope dictionary?

Comment: Because it's an endpoint on a server that I don't have edit access to, I assumed I couldn't add a property to the existing object.

Comment: Objects are dynamic. You can add/change mostly anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about just putting the counts inside an object on the scope, keyed by their id?  Then you can index into the object in the expression using the id:

```
$scope.counts = {};
function getEventsCount(calendarId) {
  if(calendarId !== '') {
    calendarService.getCalendarEvents(calendarId, fromDate, toDate).then(function (result) {
      if(isSuccessResponse(result)) {
        $scope.counts[calendarId] = result.events.length;
      } else {
        $scope.errorMessage = errorText + result.errorMessage;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item" data-ng-repeat="calendar in calendarList.calendars" data-ng-init="getEventsCount(calendar.id)">
    <a roll="button" class="btn-link" data-ng-click="showCalendar(calendar.id, calendar.summary)">{{calendar.summary}} ({{counts[calendar.id]}})</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm getting an error message TypeError: Cannot set property 'df0086fe87a1431dae5ba2f7baf0f634' of undefined

df0086fe87a1431dae5ba2f7baf0f634 in this case being the calendar ID

The error is triggered at '$scope.counts[calendarId]'

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot the $scope.counts = {}; 
Works great, thank you!!